# How do I detect all special characters in an if else statement in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

Good day,
I would like to ask about detecting all special characters in a whole string line.
This is my whole current code

```
System.out.println("Enter username: ");
usernameRegister = regScan.nextLine();

if(usernameRegister.contains(" "))
{
  System.out.println("No space");
}
else if(usernameRegister.matches("[^a-zA-Z0-9]") )
{
  System.out.println("No special char");
}
else if(usernameRegister.length()<5)
{
  System.out.println("No less than 4 chars");
}
else
{
  System.out.println("Accepted");
}
```

But the problem with my code, specifically this one

```
else if(usernameRegister.matches("[^a-zA-Z0-9]") )
```

Is that it can only detect one character in a string, how do I make it detect the whole line?

Comment: can you be more clear with an example

Comment: `usernameRegister.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9]+").split("")` this will return all non expected characters in an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like all you need is `.matches(".*[^a-zA-Z0-9].*")` – in other words 'any number of whatever, then exactly one non-alphanumeric, and then any number of whatever. A string with multiple non-alphanumerics still fits that description too.